# How can I generate a strong unipolar magnetic field to deflect at a distance?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I'm working on how to shift rain cloud, using a generated magnetic field. 
From previous weather modification, cloud seeding has been used, which makes use of chemicals to seed the cloud.

There are places on earth which experience drought. These areas do not have precipitable rain clouds within their tropospheric domain. Some other places, on the other hand, experience excessive rainfall (e.g. flooding) or unnecessary rainfall (e.g. rainfall on oceans). There is a need for a system whereby we can shift excessively precipitating rain clouds from locations where they are not necessary to places where they are needed.

Comment: Clouds are not very magnetic, I am afraid, and generating strong magnetic fields on this scale is technically, so far, out of reach of our technology. If you want to bring water from one place to another, pipes are a pretty good solution, so are irrigation channels.

Answer (score 2):

The strength of a magnetic dipole field goes with the radius to the power of minus three:

$ \vec{B}=\frac{\mu_0 m}{4 \pi r^3}(2\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0)$,

where the magnetic dipole moment $m$ is aligned with the z-axis. Such a field could be generated by a current loop or a  solenoid.

Because of the $r^{^-3}$ dependency you would need a ridiculusly high dipole moment to have a significant field at a large distance. So I do not think that it is possible to use magnetic fields to move clouds for three eminent reasons:

1. You would need very massive magnets to have a significant field strenght kilometers away from your magnet.
2. Clouds are not point like objects: moving a dilute object of several houndert or even thousand cubic kilometers in volume with dipole magnets seems impossible to me.
3. Even if you could build a setup which can generate such strong fields and which can somehow move a cloud: It would have to be mobile or even airborne: so your setup would need to be light/transportable and have a moderate energy consumption. Strong magnets are heavy and consume massive amounts of energy.

Not mentioning wind, the charge of the cloud,...

But hey feel free to calculate/think about it: as a mathematical/theoretical exercise it seems to have some challenging aspects.

Answer (score 2):

As you see above, magnetic fields are impractical. However, there are weather control [attempts that use electric fields to create ionization and hence precipitation](https://climateviewer.com/2014/03/26/cloud-ionization-electric-rainmaking-laser-guided-weather-modification/) - rain.

This technology is rather controversial, but is clearly related to the use of electrostatic fields in [commercially available precipitators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_precipitator) which are used on a much smaller scale.

Take a look at this and other related technologies such as weather modification via lasers